# Feedback from mocking with Restito

Tags: java, rest, testing, mocking, tdd

When mocking REST with Restito, is it possible to get some feedback when you mocked something incorrectly? I mean, if the request has already been sent to the stubserver from the implementation, couldn't it just record that request and present it for me?

Because sometimes it requires a lot of struggling to get the exact match of everything and it would be helpful to get some feedback when working with it.

Comment: What does the Restito documentation say about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set logging level to `DEBUG` and then you see all the requests to thestub server.